# How to trigger a sql query by clicking a button in PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql

so I am trying to make a a online shop , basically what isn't working is to execute a query when the buy clicks the "BUY" button.The query is :

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO vehicles (model,owner) VALUES ('$vehid','$id')");
```

and the button is

```
<form action=\"\" method=\"post\">   
    <input type=\"submit\" value=\"BUY\">
</form>
```

The whole code :

```
<?php
$id = $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'];


include ('config2.php');

$result = mysql_query("select * from shop_vehicule ORDER BY id DESC");
$result2 = mysql_query("select * from accounts where id = '$id'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
$credit = $row['credits'];
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $name = $row['nume'];
    $price = $row['pret'];
    $left = $credit - $price; 
    $vehid = $row['vehid'];

    echo "<p><center><b>$name</b> | $price </center>
        <a href=\"#\" class=\"topopup\">More information about $name</a></p>

    <div id=\"toPopup\"> 

        <div class=\"close\"></div>
        <span class=\"ecs_tooltip\">Press Esc to close <span class=\"arrow\"></span></span>
        <div id=\"popup_content\"> <!--your content start-->
            <p>
The $name costs $price, after you'll have $left !</p>

<form action=\"\" method=\"post\">   
    <input type=\"submit\" value=\"BUY\">
</form>

        </div> 

    </div> 

    <div class=\"loader\"></div>
    <div id=\"backgroundPopup\"></div>";
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO vehicles (model,owner) VALUES ('$vehid','$id')");   
}

mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: You ask bad questions and are at risk of losing your question-asking privileges. [You should read this before you post your next one.](http://s.tk/onhold)

Comment: `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications and will be removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices.

Comment: The sorts of questions you're asking demonstrate a lack of fundamental knowledge. What references do you have for PHP? A good book or reference site would go a long way towards unblocking your learning.

Comment: Totally agree with you @tadman.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt to help, I didn't test the codes but it should be working. Please read the comments in the codes. It explains what it does.

```
$id = $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'];

/* To use PDO the following line must be included in your config2.php

    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
    define('DB_NAME', 'database');
    define('DB_USER', 'username');
    define('DB_PASS', 'password');
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host='. DB_HOST .';dbname='. DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);

    You can either use define or put the info straight into the PDO() function but I like it when it's easy to read and modify if needed.
*/
include ('config2.php');

$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE id = :id"); //Please use PDO or MySQLi, MySQL is outdated and unsecure. For this example, I am using my favorite method which is PDO.
$query->execute(array(':id' => $id));
$account = $query->fetchObject(); //Since we only need one line, we're going to use fetchObject object.

$query2 = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM shop_vehicule ORDER BY id DESC");
$query2->execute();
$vehicules = $query2->fetchAll(); //I am using fetchAll due to multiple row will be returned.

foreach ($vehicules as $row) {
    echo '<p><center><b>'.$row['nume'].'</b> | '.$row['pret'].' </center>
        <a href="#" class="topopup">More information about $name</a></p>

    <div id="toPopup">
        <div class="close"></div>
        <span class="ecs_tooltip">Press Esc to close <span class="arrow"></span></span>
        <div id="popup_content"> <!--your content start-->
            <p>The '.$row['nume'].' costs '.$row['pret'].', after you\'ll have '.$account->credit - $row['pret'].' !</p>
            <a href="?purchase='.$row['vehid'],'">BUY</a>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="loader"></div>
    <div id="backgroundPopup"></div>';
}

// Basically what this part does is whenever the user click on the link, purchase will be set and it'll trigger the query to insert into the vehicule table then return a message if it was successful or not.
if ( isset($_GET['purchase']) ) {
    $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO vehicles (model,owner) VALUES (':vehid',':id');");
    $query->execute(array(':vehid' => $_GET['purchase'], ':id' => $id));

    if ($query) {
        echo 'Congratulations! You have successfully purchased the vehicule!';
    } else {
        echo 'An error has occured, the purchase was not complete.';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use action=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] in the form tag and make a write the MySQL Insert Code in condition where isset($_POST['Buy']) is true.

Answer (score -1):

you can do this in php, but in 2 different files. 
The first will have the form, and the second will read the POST value and perform the query

Example(please fill missing pieces)

File 1 . php

```
    <form action="file2.php" method="post">   
        <input type="hidden" value=<?php echo $vehid;?>" name="vehid">
        <input type="hidden" value=<?php echo $id;?>" name="id">
        <input type="submit" value="BUY">
    </form>
```

File2.php

```
$vehid=$_POST['model'];
$id=$_POST['id'];
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO vehicles (model,owner) VALUES ('$vehid','$id')");
```

For a complete tutorial see http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: Please [do not link to w3schools](http://w3fools.com/). That has many hazardously out of date examples and perpetuates some poisonously bad programming habits. It does way more harm than good.